# angularjs $http is forcing Content-type header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Im trying to post a form, using this:

```
$http({
                url: authUrl,
                method: 'POST',
                data: params,
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
                }
            }).success($scope.getEmailData).error($scope.httpError);
```

but when i check in fiddler the content-type was sent as `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

is this a bug or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Content-Type` instead of `Content-type` for the key.

Also, if `params` is undefined, it can cause issues. Try setting data to `''`. ie.

```
$http({
            url: authUrl,
            method: 'POST',
            data: params || '',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
            }
        }).success($scope.getEmailData).error($scope.httpError);
```